# Autocomplete doesn't work with javascript generated input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you generate a login overlay with javascript (via ajax loaded content or with JS templates), browsers usually (firefox, safari) don't use autocomplete in these input fields. It's really annoying, do you have any ideas how can I fix this?

Do I need to generate a hidden form inside the original HTML and move this form into this overlay?

Thanks,
Andras

Comment: `<input ... autocomplete=ON />`?

Comment: Example of code that doesn't do autocomplete?

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the same, using javascript to produce and get values from input fields. They would not autocomplete any text. I discovered that placing the input field in `<form></form>` allowed autocomplete to work as it should. I wasn't including the form element at first because I wasn't submitting any form, just making an ajax call. And now that use use `<form>` you just gotta prevent the default form submit and make the ajax call instead. For example `<form onsubmit="return false;">`